# Why are setters overwritten instead of being called when used within web components?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I am attempting to learn how to make a custom table with web components, and I'm trying to define properties on my custom elements with getters and setters. Here is a very simple table with one column, and a custom row element that has a `line_number` property. Creating a custom table and then setting `line_number` works as expected, with the setter being called and putting the value in the appropriate element. However, if `line_number` is set by the custom table's constructor as in `serial-log-setter-broken` below, the setter is not called and appears to be deleted (attempting to call it later does nothing).

```js
customElements.define('serial-log-setter-broken', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    }).innerHTML = `
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Line Number</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>`

    this.rows = []

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      this.rows[i] = document.createElement('tr', {
        is: 'serial-log-entry'
      })

      // .line_number's setter isn't called here, and seems to be deleted instead
      this.rows[i].line_number = i + 1

      this.shadowRoot.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(this.rows[i])
    }
  }
})

customElements.define('serial-log-setter-working', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    }).innerHTML = `
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Line Number</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>`

    this.rows = []

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      this.rows[i] = document.createElement('tr', {
        is: 'serial-log-entry'
      })
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(this.rows[i])
    }
  }
})

customElements.define('serial-log-entry', class extends HTMLTableRowElement {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.innerHTML = '<td>1</td>'

    this._line_number_cell = this.querySelector('td')
  }

  get line_number() {
    return Number(this._line_number_cell.textContent)
  }
  set line_number(v) {
    console.log('Setter called')
    this._line_number_cell.textContent = Number(v)
  }
}, {
  extends: 'tr'
})

console.log('This will print nothing')
document.getElementsByTagName('serial-log-setter-broken')[0].rows.forEach((v, i) => {
  v.line_number = i + 1
})

console.log('This will print "Setter called" 4 times')
document.getElementsByTagName('serial-log-setter-working')[0].rows.forEach((v, i) => {
  v.line_number = i + 1
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Setter overwritten</title>
</head>

<body>
  <serial-log-setter-broken></serial-log-setter-broken>
  <serial-log-setter-working></serial-log-setter-working>
</body>

</html>
```

Why does the setter work when used from outside the web component, but gets deleted when used from inside it?

Note: `serial-log-setter-broken` and `serial-log-setter-working` are nearly identical, and differ in whether the `line_number` setter is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It about the order of definition.

The `serial-log-setter-broken` is defined and executed before the `serial-log-entry` is defined. You can check this by adding a log message into the constructor of the `serial-log-setter-broken` element. The log message is printed before the "This will print nothing" message.

It is a strange behavior. I wasn't aware of it myself.

When you move the definition of the `serial-log-entry` above the `serial-log-setter-broken` definition then it works.

Note, you may reconsider extending built-in elements as Safari (the new IE) refuses to support the "is" attribute. See [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182671) and [here](https://github.com/WebKit/standards-positions/issues/97).

Comment: I didn't explain why it's overwritten. Because the custom element is not yet defined at the moment when the constructor of the `serial-log-setter-broken` element is called, it sets a `line_number` property on the `tr` element (which still is not yet extended). This fact overrides the `line_number` setter after the `serial-log-entry` is finally defined.

Comment: Also note, I tried `await Promise.all([
  customElements.whenDefined("serial-log-entry"),
  customElements.whenDefined("serial-log-setter-working"),
  customElements.whenDefined("serial-log-setter-broken"),
]);` before running the setters and it makes no difference. It's because the constructor is called anyway (after parsing the HTML) so waiting for elements definition to complete makes no difference. Unless you construct the DOM after the fact.

Comment: Interesting, so it looks like the constructor is called as soon as it's defined. I assume that's because it's called by the HTML parser, rather than by another bit of script, as for normal Javascript classes.

Fortunately, my current project doesn't need to support iOS, but I'll have to keep that issue in mind as well...

Comment: @Densaugeo Actually, what's happening is this. The HTML parser registered the use of 2 custom elements. At that point there are of a type of HTMLUnknownElement. Then the script executes. With the first instruction is registers the "broken" element. Since there's an element in the DOM that wants this definition it is being initialized (constructor is called). It creates a shadow DOM where another custom element is used, but this element is not yet defined (at that point). Hence the whole issue. After registering the element, the `line_number` property is already set, so no setters/getters.